# How is the powershell $profile resolved?

Tags: powershell

The operations department has changed the location of the home network storage and with that my powershell profile stopped loading. If I print ´$PROFILE´ I get

```
WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

As you can see it is missing the first part of the part to my home folder where the ´WindowsPowerShell´ folder is located. So my question is, how is ´$PROFILE´ resolved in PowerShell? Is it built up from environment variables or how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find what you need here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx

Edit: so I guess that it is the %HOME% environment variable that is missing in your setup.

Comment: Please summarize your link (links can go down)

Comment: The `%HOME%` was set, the one that was missing was some group policy pointing out where the "My Documents" folder was located. This was due to a change in the infrastructure.